# How do you disable swipe history navigation in Chrome?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, microsoft-surface

On my Surface Pro, when I drag my finger across the browser window, Chrome will navigate back and forth through the browsing history.

[image: example video]
<sub>(source: [gifyoutube.com](https://share.gifyoutube.com/KYEOZN.gif))</sub>

<sup>click to open on Youtube</sup>](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3fXrQ9TM0eI)

How do I disable this feature?

Comment: Are you swiping from the left to right or right to left?

Comment: @vembutech Both. The former navigates back, the latter forward.

Comment: This is not Windows or Surface specific. The same solution works on other operating systems/devices, including Chrome OS/Chromebooks.

Comment: Is this not a function of the OS ? It's a 'shortcut' which is provided to the application, by the OS.

Comment: I found this question even though I’m using Vivaldi on Mac OS. @djsmiley2k’s comment helped me. The setting is called “Swipe between pages” in the system preferences under “Trackpad” and “More Gestures.”

Comment: Chrome 80 removed the hidden setting to disable this feature. There is an issue where people are complaining about it: https://crbug.com/1060053

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Updated: Q1 2021

This can be disabled on Windows by passing the following flag on the command line:

```
--disable-features="TouchpadOverscrollHistoryNavigation"
```

Comment: I no longer have this issue or have a device where I could reproduce this. A quick online research indicates that this is the the current correct solution though.

Answer (score 30):

1. Go to `chrome://flags/#overscroll-history-navigation`
2. Disable the **Overscroll history navigation** experiment:

   [image]

Comment: This worked for me on Chrome OS.

Comment: There are some people that are still having issues with disabling this: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/5616407?hl=en

Comment: This flag is no longer available in version 89.0.4389.82

Answer (score 11):

You can also pass

```
--overscroll-history-navigation=0
```

as startup parameter to chrome

Comment: I've been looking for this for a while, thanks! No one mentioned the start up flag param at all and I was looking all over for it.

Answer (score 4):

It works for MacOS to disabling of swiping.

Just run Terminal of MacOS and paste  and run this command

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool false
```

After that close chrome and run it again.

Comment: Bless you sir, I've been having screaming fits when Chrome would go back while I was scrolling around but I didn't want to change "swipe between pages" for everything.